# Create a text file to save data from each scraped URL

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have done the following:

```
for url in url_list:
    print (url)
    #concat URL with http// and send it
    if url[:4] != 'http':
        url = 'http://' + url

    response = requests.get(url)
    response
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    print(soup)

with open("copy.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write(str(soup))
```

I would like to create a text file for each scraped URL. Currently it's saving everything to one file.

Comment: Open the file _before_ the `for` loop.

Comment: yes, but this won't create new file for each URL right?

Comment: No. If you want that, then open the file _inside_ the `for` loop and change the name each time.

Answer (score 1):

Open the file inside the `for` loop with a different name each time.

```
id = 0
for url in url_list:
    print (url)
    #concat URL with http// and send it
    if url[:4] != 'http':
        url = 'http://' + url

    response = requests.get(url)
    response
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    print(soup)
    # Save to "copy_1.txt", "copy_2.txt", etc
    id += 1
    with open(f"copy_{id}.txt", "w") as file:
        file.write(str(soup))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. You just have to create the file within the for loop, and add a identifier to the filename, so that is not overwritten.

```
for url in url_list:
    # print (url)
    # concat URL with http// and send it
    if url[:4] != 'http':
        url = 'http://' + url

    response = requests.get(url)
    response
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    # print(soup)

    # I would use an identifier from the url however you can use an index instead.
    url_identifier = url_list.index(url)

    with open(f"copy_{url_identifier}.txt", "w") as file:
        file.write(str(soup))
```